# trying to fetch matched and non-matched values from same table

Tags: mysql, database

Im trying to fetch matched and non-matched values from same table,but its giving double value This is My query

```
select
  sum(pp.redeem_points_used) as OnlineRewards,
  sum(pp1.redeem_points_used) as GlocalRewards,
  pp.user_details_id
from
  panalist_redeem_points as pp,
  panalist_redeem_points as pp1
where
  pp.transaction_id not like 'G%' and pp1.transaction_id like 'G%'
group by pp.transaction_id;
```

Comment: can you show your table structure???

Comment: Needless alias `pp1`. You can fetch all from `pp`.

Comment: il explain the issue ex: redeem_points_used =100,in that i spend 50rs on online and 50rs on glocalreward ,that i identified through transaction_id bez glocalrewad begin with GM ,now i want to show both online rewards and glocalrewards

Comment: Include sample data, your result and expected result. Do not post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just one table selected :

```
select
  sum((pp.transaction_id not like 'G%')*pp.redeem_points_used) as OnlineRewards,
  sum((pp.transaction_id like 'G%')*pp.redeem_points_used) as GlocalRewards,
  pp.user_details_id
from
  panalist_redeem_points as pp
group by pp.transaction_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur valuable answer